# Cannot make tomcat render index.jsp page in different folder

Tags: jsp, jsf, tomcat

I have a web app structure as follows:

```
Tomcat
 |__ webapps
     |__ manager
     |__ ROOT
     |__ myApp1
         |__ web
             |__ logon.jsp
         |__ jsp
             |__ Home.jsp
         |__ WEB-INF
         |__ pki
             |__ index.jsp
```

This Home.jsp page contains links:

```
 - Logon using uID/password -> myApp1/jsp/logon.jsf
 - Logon using code         -> myApp1/pki/index.jsp
```

I can click and open the page: `myApp1/jsp/logon.jsf`

But I cannot open `myApp1/pki/index.jsp`

The page says: This page cannot be displayed

I have `faces-navigation.xml`, `web.xml`, `faces-config` in my `WEB-INF`

But I am not sure how to configure this `pki` folder and `index.jsp` page

It's so hard to figure out someone else's code :(

Does anyone know what I am missing?

Comment: "*This page cannot be displayed*". What is the status code, 404? Are you using JSF? How did you map `FacesServlet` in that case (which URL pattern was it (`FacesServlet`) mapped to)?

Comment: no 404 code. I only see logon.jsp. I think in faces-navigation or web.xml  the logon.jsp is configured to read as .jsf.........